# IE7 hover on div being lost when you touch a child element of that div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

**In Theory**

I have a div (container) that when hovered over one of its child divs appear (drop-down). Drop-down contains links images etc. and when I leave it and container then drop-down disappears.

```
<div id="container">
  <div>Hover over me to see extra stuff</div>
  <div id="drop-down">
     <div>
       <img />
     </div>
     <div>
       <a />
       <p><span>Info</span><span>More</span></p>
     </div>
     <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the jQuery

```
$('#container').hover(
  function(){ $(this).find('#drop-down').addClass('hover'); },
  function(){ $(this).find('#drop-down').removeClass('hover'); }
);
```

Heres the CSS for hover

```
#container #drop-down {left: -9999px;}
#container .hover {left: 0;}
```

**In Practice**

In every browser other than IE7 it works perfectly but when I highlight over the spans in the first containing div in drop-down then drop-down dissappears for some reason as if I had left container.

**The Question**

I have been slamming my head against a wall for nearly 3 hours trying to find all the ie7 bugs I could to see if any were relevant but sadly with no luck. I originally thought it could be 'z-index' issue but as it is actually displaying above the content below this can't be the case (and I've tried it by setting 'position:relative; z-index:9999;' on both the p and the spans). Other than that I am completely stumped. I do however know that the any items below that div (e.g. the image tag in the example above) do create the issue after skirting round the spans on the padding of the p.

Further clarification:
I've found it is to do the elements the lying underneath the spans but as they aren't showing through I have no idea how to fix it. Also, it doesn't matter what element is underneath just if there is a div underneath that you can "enter" (i.e. you are not already in it) then you lose the hover and drop-down disappears.

I know I haven't put up the CSS but can anyone think of any reason why this could be happening? Also, I have disabled all CSS working directly on it and it still is affected but this issue.

Comment: instead of using javascript, try this and see if it works

.container .drop-down {display:none;}
.container:hover .drop-down {display:block;}

Comment: could you post your hover class?

Comment: @Zoidberg +1 for the solution which is correct in the vast majority of these javscript for simple hover-effect cases

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, I didn't post it as an answer because I wasn't sure its what he wanted as that answer won't work in IE 6.

Comment: Uhm, and I think op is using id's, so should be, #container #drop-down {display:none;} #container:hover #drop-down {display:block;}, but works well.

Comment: As a clarification the problem seems to be that for some reason the span is not a sub-element of container. Hence when rolled over you are effectively no longer hovering over container.

Comment: @Zoidberg I've tried changing the CSS and so I'm no longer using jQuery and the issue is still there.

Sorry for double post

Comment: Put a background color on the span.  If its transparent IE could think its not in it anymore if your just hovering over the background.

Comment: @Zoidberg that fixed it. Could you post to an article or something explaining why it works as adding a background-color seems like the last thing in the world that would fix it to me.
Also, post it as an answer and I'll accept it - if you want the rep :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in the comments

Putting a background color on the span will make the hover work.  For some reason when you hover over a transparent background in IE, it considers the mouse to not be in the dom object  (or in this case, the span) anymore, but instead in the element below it and calls the mouse out event.

Microsoft considers this a bug and links to this [blog entry](http://blog.rednael.com/2009/09/01/TrappingMouseEventsOnTransparentInputElementsOrTextareasInIE.aspx) from there [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536948(VS.85).aspx) entry

Comment: OMG. I can't believe there's still bugs in IE I wasn't aware of. Thank you.

Comment: There are only two infinite things in the universe, and one is the number of bugs in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Have found what is causing elements to disappear in old version of IE.
Copy add this to your css

```
div { display: inline-block; }

div { display: block; }
```

[This](http://haslayout.net/haslayout) explains the bug nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
div { display: inline-block; }  div { display: block; }
```

This worked for me... wow what a pain.